# Statement "else if" dont work to validate input

Tags: jquery

Just got to do the "if" statement, but I don't understand why the "else if" does not work.

Jquery

```
$('#submit-register').click(function () {
    // Works Fine
    if (0 == $('#last').val().length) {
        $('#last').addClass('error-input');
      // Doesn't Work
    } else if (0 == $('#name').val().length) {
        $('#name').addClass('error-input');
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no else if in JQuery

Comment: @ItayGal yes, there is an else..if in javascript.

Comment: if the first condition is true, the second will never be reached. this is how javascript (and most other language) if else if statements work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to validate each condition separately.

to do that you need to remove the `else`.

```
$('#submit-register').click(function () {
    // Works Fine
    if (0 == $('#last').val().length) {
        $('#last').addClass('error-input');
    } 

    if (0 == $('#name').val().length) {
        $('#name').addClass('error-input');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your might had to open console from check the values for testing

```
$('#submit-register').click(function () {
    // Work Fine
    console.log("first if value = "+$('#last').val().length);
    console.log("second if value = "+ $('#name').val().length);
    if (0 == $('#last').val().length) {
      console.log("first if is true");
        $('#last').addClass('error-input');
      // Dont Wok
    } else if (0 == $('#name').val().length) {
      console.log("second if is true");
        $('#name').addClass('error-input');
    }
else {
      console.log("no if is true");
}

});
```